# moment js compare time is between with date

Tags: momentjs

I had a start and end time, but start time is greater than end time

I want to check if my inputted time is between the start and end time

```
var startTime = moment('12:30 PM', 'h:mma');
var endTime = moment('1:00 AM', 'h:mma');
var inputtedTime = moment('12:00 AM', 'h:mma');
```

As we can see, `inputtedTime` is between `startTime` and `endTime` without the date intervention.

```
12:30 PM
01:30 PM
02:30 PM
......
10:30 PM
11:30 PM
12:00 AM  // <---------
12:30 AM
01:30 AM
```

But when I started to compare using moment js, the result becomes false. Where in fact, I compare the start and end time first (if `startTime` isBefore `endTime`, we must add 1 day to the `endTime`)

```
var isTimeValid = true;
if(startTime.isBefore(endTime) == false) {
  endTime.add(1, "days");
}
isTimeValid = inputtedTime.isBetween(startTime, endTime);
console.log(isTimeValid);  // false
```

How can we output the result to true?

here's my fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/aSc4R/221/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `endTime` is sometimes the next day, and you have to add one day to that.  But in that case, you also have to check if your `inputTime` is between midnight and the `endTime`, and if it is, add a day to the `inputTime`, too.

Here's some code with test times right before, at, and after midnight with the conditions checked and adjusted. All three test times are now valid.

Here's a working JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/joewilson/174exdnu/

```
var testTimesThatShouldBeValid = ['11:59 PM', '12:00 AM', '12:01 AM'];

testTimesThatShouldBeValid.forEach(function(testTime) {
  var isTimeValid = false;
  var startTime = moment('12:30 PM', 'h:mma');
  var midnight = moment('12:00 AM', 'h:mma');
  var endTime = moment('1:00 AM', 'h:mma');
  var inputtedTime = moment(testTime, 'h:mma');

  if (endTime.isBefore(startTime)) {
    if (inputtedTime.isBetween(midnight, endTime, null, '[]')) {
      inputtedTime.add(1, 'days');
      console.log("adjusted input time to next day");
    }

    endTime.add(1, 'days');
    console.log("adjusted end time to next day");
  }

  console.log(inputtedTime.format());
  console.log(startTime.format());
  console.log(endTime.format());

  isTimeValid = inputtedTime.isBetween(startTime, endTime);
  console.log(isTimeValid); // between start and end
})
```